# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/ User has no profile

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I want to create a profile for each user but I received this error message and this my function in :

**views.py :**

```
   @login_required
   def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                               request.FILES ,instance=request.user.profile)
  
    if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
        user_from =u_form.save()
        profile_form= p_form.save(False)
        user_from=profile_form
        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
        return redirect('list')


else:
    u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)                             #instance=request.user.profile)
args = {}
   
args['u_form'] = u_form
args['p_form'] = p_form
return render(request, 'users/profile.html',args)
```

*register user* :

```
  def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
        return redirect('login')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

why this code don't working? I'm trying to create a registration form for users.
**models.py :**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True, primary_key=True, default=None)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self):
    super().save()
```

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: this user has not a profile

Comment: please share your modals

Comment: it's done ,it's modified

Comment: @bdemirka so you can help me please !